# nested cross-validation with custom folding

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

My data has a column called `pid` and records with the same `pid` should not be leaked between train-test splits. I have a 2-layers stacked model -

- Internal layer builds an internal-prediction vector by cross-val-predicting on the train-data
- I then build an external model on the original train-data + internal prediction vector
- I then assess performance on the test-data

This process should be repeated X5.

The best way I could think of was split by `pid % 25` in the external layer and `pid % 5` in the internal layer.

The code came out cumbersome and not very pythonic. Is there a better way to do that? Am I missing some neat and clean usage of sklearn/python or is there some fundamental flaw in my design?

```
N = 5

for external_fold in range(N):

    ex_test = [x for x in range(N**2) if external_fold*N <= x % (N**2) < (external_fold+1)*N]
    ex_train = [x for x in range(N**2) if x not in ex_test]
    ex_train_index = X[(X.pid % N**2).isin(ex_train)].index
    ex_test_index = X[(X.pid % N**2).isin(ex_test)].index
    ...
    for internal_fold in range(N):
        in_train_index = X[(X.pid % N)!=internal_fold].index
        in_test_index = X[(X.pid % N)==internal_fold].index
        # build a vector of internal model predictions

    # build external model and assess performance
```

Comment: Using [`skelarn.cross_validation.KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.KFold) instead of trying to build your own solution might be a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

You have two needs that have only recently been addressed in Scikit-Learn, and should be included in the next released version:

**Cross-validation strategies with correlated samples kept together**

The new [CV splitter classes](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/classes.html#splitter-classes) now include `LabelKFold` and `LabelShuffleSplit` both designed to handle the case you consider where elements with the same `pid` should be in the same test portion.

**Nested cross-validation**

The cross-validation iterator API has been redesigned to better support nested cross-validation. You should no longer need to pass data-dependent parameters to a cross-validation strategy constructor. Thus nesting a `GridSearchCV` within a `GridSearchCV`, each with their own `cv` parameter, should meet your needs.

Please note that this API is still very fresh and open to change.